# Scala check the different between 2 objects

Tags: scala, playframework

I am building a play scala app with mysql. And need to implement history of the table. The ideas of me is to record all changes on the records on some table. So if there is an update from client, app will check the current value on the database and the new data from user.
And will only input the different on the history table.
Example : id, name, address, ...

If the user send new data and only the name column that modified, I will only input the history of name with old value and new value.

Currently I check it manually one by one the column using if, which make me code more when I have more column on the table.

My question is, is there any good way to check the different instead comparing one by one using if?

Here my Code example on my app (you can see I use 4 if there, and I will have another table that has more columns) :

```
Motor.findById(motorEdit.id) match {
  case Some(motor) => {
    val hisText = ArrayBuffer.empty[String]
    val hisMsg: (String, String) => String = {
      (Messages.get("mtr_his_upt") + " \"" + _ + "\" -> \"" + _ + "\"")
    }
    if(motor.name.compareTo(motorEdit.name) != 0)
      hisText += hisMsg(motor.name, motorEdit.name)
    if(motor.types.compareTo(motorEdit.types) != 0)
      hisText += hisMsg(motor.types, motorEdit.types)
    if(motor.code.getOrElse("").compareTo(motorEdit.code.getOrElse("")) != 0)
      hisText += hisMsg(motor.code.getOrElse(""), motorEdit.code.getOrElse(""))
    if(motor.visible != motorEdit.visible)
      hisText += hisMsg(motor.visible.toString, motorEdit.visible.toString)

    val updateNumber = motor.updateNumber + 1
    Motor.updateById(motor.id).withAttributes(
      'name -> motorEdit.name,
      'types -> motorEdit.types,
      'code -> motorEdit.code,
      'visible -> motorEdit.visible,
      'update_number -> updateNumber)

    hisText.map { value =>
      MotorHistory.createWithAttributes(
        'user_id -> currentUser.id,
        'motor_id -> motor.id,
        'history -> value,
        'update_number -> updateNumber
      )
    }
    retOk
  }
  case None => retNotFound
}
```

Maybe I will explain why I use the design history table is because I have some table that need to join more than 2 table, but I want to keep the history in 1 table.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to store history of your database is to create separate history for each table. So if you have user table you have to create additional table lets say user_hist. for me you have a better view for all columns an you can easier check what was changed. An if you use ORM you can write your own equals to compate those object (in model of course)

Comment: Hi Mical, I am not really understand what are you suggest. Currently I has 1 table with 1 history table.
The history table is only 'id', 'created', 'history'. Which the history column will only record the different update of user table. If there are 2 columns diff, so it will insert two record on history table

Comment: I meant that the best approach to solve it is to create history with all information even with those which wasn't changed.

Comment: Hi michal, I understand what you mean. But those design does not align with my apps. Example is when I have a motor and color table, they are separated tables. But I want to centralize the history on motor history only, so when there is a user edit the color, it will generate the history on motor instead on the color history.

Answer (score -1):

If the object is a `case class`  then that by default will have the `equals` operator.

```
case class User(name: String, address: String)

val A = User("Bob", "1 Green Street")

val B = User("Bob", "1 Green Street")

A == B
>true
```

If you cannot use a case class you will have to redefine `equals` and `hashCode` on the class to suit your needs.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, this will tell if they are different, not what the difference is.